# How to do pagination after every 10 comments in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pagination

I have a list of comments formed.  The client wants a new page after every 10 comments, so comment 11 will be on page 2, and so on for as many pages as they get.  The commets are formed on a .ashx page becuase of an issue I had with the regular .aspx.cs page.  Simply put, how do I accomplish this?

Here is the code of the .ashx page:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{

    // ****************************************
    if (context.Request["postform"] == "1")
    {

        videomessage myVideoMessage = new videomessage();

        myVideoMessage.video_id = context.Request["video_id"];
        myVideoMessage.first_name_submitter = context.Request["first_name_submitter"];
        myVideoMessage.last_initial_submitter = context.Request["last_initial_submitter"];
        myVideoMessage.message = context.Request["message"];
        myVideoMessage.status = "0";

        myVideoMessage.Save();
    }
    // ****************************************

    // ****************************************
    StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


    // PULL VIDEOMESSAGES FOR VIDEO_ID
    videomessage[] myCommentsList = new videomessage().Listing("video_id", context.Request["video_id"], "entry_date" , "DESC");

    // FORM COMMENTS IF MORE THAN ONE COMMENT EXISTS
    foreach (videomessage tmpMessage in myCommentsList)
    {
        if (tmpMessage.status == "0" || tmpMessage.status == "1")
        {
            myStringBuilder.Append("<div class=\"comment_box\">");
            myStringBuilder.Append("<p class=\"comment_date\">");
            myStringBuilder.Append(Utility.FormatShortDate(tmpMessage.entry_date) + " " + tmpMessage.first_name_submitter + " " + tmpMessage.last_initial_submitter + "." + "</p>");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpMessage.message))
            {
                myStringBuilder.Append("<p>" + tmpMessage.message + "</p>");
                myStringBuilder.Append("</div>");
            }
        }
    }
    string return_str = myStringBuilder.ToString();

    // IF NO COMMENTS RETURN THIS
    if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(return_str) )  return_str = "<p>No comments currently exist for this video.</p>";
    // ****************************************

    // RETURN STRING        
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(return_str);
}
```

I know there will need to be some math involved as well as assigning it to variables, but I am still new to .NET so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pagenumber = commentNumber / pagesize (using integer division)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Linq

```
const int pageSize = 10;
var paginatedComments = comments.Skip((page ?? 0) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

(*) page is input from request

Maybe a little outdated, but have a look at the nerddinner tutorial (http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf), which describes a pagination principle for MVC using a custom PaginatedList class

```
    public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T> {
        public int PageIndex  { get; private set; }
        public int PageSize   { get; private set; }
        public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize) {
             PageIndex = pageIndex;
             PageSize = pageSize;
             TotalCount = source.Count();
             TotalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);
             this.AddRange(source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage {
           get {
              return (PageIndex > 0);
           }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage {
            get {
               return (PageIndex+1 < TotalPages);
            }
        }
   }
```

Alternative solution would be using a jquery approach (see http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins), but I have no experience with either of the plugins suggested on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

```
currentPage=1
NextPageFirstRecord=(currrentpage-1)*noRecordsPerPage
pageCount=totalrecords/noRecordsPerPage
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Where does noRecordsPerPage get assigned?